# Break Outside Loop with Previous Example

Tags: python, break

UPDATED:

This Code Works:

```
# North Carolina Sales Tax Estimator
# Estimates the Amount of Tax You Should Pay in North Carolina

# Defines the Current 2012 Tax Rate
nctaxrate = 0.07

# Defines the tax variable by multipling subtotal by the current nc tax rate
# tax = subtotal * nctaxrate

# Defines the total variable by adding the tax variable to the subtotal variable
# total = subtotal + tax

# Defines the Subtotal from an Input of the User's Purchase Amount
def main():
    print("\t\t\tThis is the NC Sales Tax Estimator")
    print("\t\t Input Your Total Purchases Below\n")

    while True:
        subtotal = float(input("Enter the total price of your purchases:\t$").strip())
        if subtotal == -1: break
        tax = subtotal * nctaxrate
        total = subtotal + tax

        print("\tSUBTOTAL: $", subtotal)
        print("\t     TAX: $", tax)
        print("\t   TOTAL: $", total)

# if this script is called directly by Python, run the main() function
# (if it is loaded as a module by another Python script, don't)
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Here is the Original Question:

So I am learning Python and asked a previous question yesterday and was supplied with an awesome set of code that I decided to modify to work with an NC Sales Tax Estimator Program I wanted to create.

The one thing is that I am getting a break out loop error that I don't quite understand.  I've searched and tried to understand the meaning but I know the code worked before.  Also the tax code program I created from scratch :) worked before trying to add the fancy ability to submit many inputs in a loop until the user wanted to 'exit'.

Here is the Code:

```
# North Carolina Sales Tax Estimator
# Estimates the Amount of Tax You Should Pay in North Carolina

# Defines the Current 2012 Tax Rate
nctaxrate = 0.07

# Defines the tax variable by multipling subtotal by the current nc tax rate
tax = subtotal * nctaxrate

# Defines the total variable by adding the tax variable to the subtotal variable
total = subtotal + tax

# Defines the Subtotal from an Input of the User's Purchase Amount
def main():
    print("\t\t\tThis is the NC Sales Tax Estimator")
    print("\t\t Input Your Total Purchases Below")

while True:
    subtotal = float(input("Enter the total price of your purchases (or 'exit' to quit) :\$").strip())
    if subtotal.lower()=='exit':
        break

    try:
        subtotal = int(subtotal)
    except ValueError:
        print("That wasn't a number!")

    try:
        print("\tSUBTOTAL: $", subtotal)
        print("\t     TAX: $", tax)
        print("\t   TOTAL: $", total)
    except KeyError:
        print("")

# if this script is called directly by Python, run the main() function
# (if it is loaded as a module by another Python script, don't)
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

P.S.  I only added the KeyError because I researched that you must have an error statement after a try.  I'm just a beginner so I'm attempting to create programs myself and reading "Python for the Absolute Beginner".

UPDATE:

I fixed the indentation but now I get the following traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/LearningPython/taxestimator.py", line 30, in <module>
    tax = subtotal * nctaxrate
NameError: name 'subtotal' is not defined
```

I thought I defined it in the input ie.

```
subtotal = float(input("Enter the total price of your purchases (or 'exit' to quit) :\$").strip())
```

Is it because the other defines (tax and total) that use the defined subtotal are defined before subtotal is defined?  I tried moving them below the defined subtotal but it didn't work still.

Thanks for any Advice.

Best,

Steven

Comment: At a cursory glance, none of your indentation looks right, which would cause issues.  Is this *exactly* how it looks in your file?

Comment: I've updated the post and found another error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue that you have is that Python requires whitespace to scope methods.  Without that, then statements will run not as intended - for example:

```
while True:
    subtotal = float(input("Enter the total price of your purchases (or 'exit' to quit) :\$").strip())
if subtotal.lower()=='exit':
    break
```

will not break out of the loop with valid input (it will if you put a string there, but that's another matter).  Also, if everything is to be in the scope of `main()`, every statement requires one level of indentation (or four lines of whitespace, if you prefer).  As it stands, your `while` won't run in the scope of `main()`.

Also, you make reference to `subtotal` before you actually give it a value.  Since `subtotal`wasn't properly initialized, you won't have a value to use for it.

You would want to rewrite your code such that `tax` and `total` are defined *after* you define `subtotal`.

```
while True:
    subtotal = float(input("Enter the total price of your purchases (or 'exit' to quit) :\$").strip())
    if subtotal.lower()=='exit':
        break
    tax = subtotal * nctaxrate
    total = subtotal + tax
```

Finally, if `subtotal`, `total`, and `tax` are properly defined (which, after the above, they will be), there will be no need for the superflous `try...except` statement when you wish to print the values out.

Comment: after eliminating the try...except and moving the defines under the while statement, I received another error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/LearningPython/tax2.py", line 32, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/LearningPython/tax2.py", line 20, in main
    if subtotal.lower()=='exit':
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'    -- Thanks for the all the help btw.

Comment: @Steven:  Wouldn't expect a float to have a String method.  How about instead of using a string, you use an integer (say -1) to break the loop?  `if subtotal == -1: break`

Comment: That fixed it.  Thanks Makoto and Joran.

Answer (score 0):

```
if subtotal.lower()=='exit':
    break
```

needs to be indented probably ... unless that was just a typo when entering the question

Comment: I'd say, "wait for clarification from the OP" before assuming that this is the case.  If it is, there's a bit more to indent than just that line.

Comment: yeah actually looks like everything below that also needs to be indented ... but certainly those two lines

Comment: Yeah, it was the indent problem but now it gives another error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/LearningPython/taxestimator.py", line 30, in <module>
    tax = subtotal * nctaxrate
NameError: name 'subtotal' is not defined

Comment: I thought I defined it with the input, though.